# How to make sense of " I know that p but I could be wrong as to p"? ( Faillibilism)

Tags: epistemology, reference-request, knowledge, modal-logic, probability

- There is a well known modal fallacy regarding knowledge which says that if some subject *s* knows that p, then p cannot be false, and therefore , p is a necessarily true proposition.

Source : [ by Schwartz, author of *Possible Worlds*]  [https://www.sfu.ca/~swartz/modal_fallacy.htm#knows](https://www.sfu.ca/%7Eswartz/modal_fallacy.htm#knows)

- I want to talk about this other fallacy : if *s* knows that p, then *s* is necessarily right about p.
- Sure, it is true that " necessarily ( if *s* knows that p, *s* is right about p) ", but that does not mean that " if *s* knows that p, then s is necessarily right about p". In other words , knowledge does not require infaillibility.
- However, I cannot prevent myself from feeling a tension between : (1) s mustn't be right by luck ( knowledge requires a justification)  and (2) s need not to be necessarily right.
- How can a justification yield a belief that is contingently right.
- Certainly, there must be some room between random contingency ( getting it right by luck) and necessity. How to make this idea precise? Could concepts pertaining to probability be helpfull here?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but I am not feeling the tension. Empirical justification relies on empirical, and hence contingent, facts and circumstances, so it typically yields only contingently true beliefs. If they happen to be necessarily true *that* would be luck. On [reliabilist theories of justification](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/reliabilism/#ProRelForJus), beliefs are justified when produced by reliable processes, but reliable processes produce true beliefs only *most* of the time. Being right isn't luck, but it isn't certainty either, empirical regularities are contingent.

Answer (score -2):

> There is a well known modal fallacy regarding knowledge which says that if some subject s knows that p, then p cannot be false, and therefore , p is a necessarily true proposition.

Well, there is a well-known syllogism, called "hypothetical syllogism", and we can apply it to solve this question:

> 1. If S knows that p, then p is true;
> 2. If p is true, then p cannot be false;
> 3. Therefore, If S knows that p, then p cannot be false;

Problem solved.

We could have considered the relevant counterfactual instead:

> If S knows that p, then it could not have been possible that p be false.

But this conditional is false...

Comment: How do you read premise (2)?  T --> Nec( ~F)  or Nec ( T --> ~F) ?  ( With " Nec" meaning " necessarily")

Comment: @FloridusFloridi I read that as nonsense. This is metaphysical gobbledegook. Alternatively, try to explain to me the notion of "necessity" without assuming it first.